# JAQL append constant string

Tags: jjaql

On JAQL Shell, I have a variable that writes into my HDFS location.  The variable use write function and writes to HDFS location.

I want to append two more additional constant strings.  How do I do that?

Comment: varWrite -> write(del(location= '/tmp/' ,delimiter='\x1c',quoted=false, schema=schema [ string? ,string? ,string? ,string? ,string? ,string? ,string? ,string? ,string? ,string? ,string? ,string? ,string? ,string? ,string? ]));

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to write varWrite variable in a delimited file with the schema you specified but the current variable doesnt contain additional constants

then

before calling to write function do another transformation of varWrite and include all with two additional constant which you want to add 
varWrite -> transform { *, 
                        CONSTANT1, 
                        CONSTANT2 } -> write(del())
and modify your schema accordingly